# jQuery each() function control the same element

Tags: jquery

I have a question that I can't figure how to solve this.

I have a huge form where I have "pilots" for car session. In my fields, I need to detect if the current field has a **length >= 2**.

If one of them is true, I need to show a special box for a warning.

I'm actually using a each(function) on a onChange function.

The problem is if the first value return true and the second return false, my warning will hide.

I would like to know if there is a kind of "break" or "continue" in each() function.

My code

```
function check_dizaine(){

$('.check_dizaine').each(function()
{
    if($(this).val().length >= 2)
    {

        $('#attention_pilotes').show();

        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #daa421');
        $(this).css('background','#f8ecc9');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #a1a1a1');
        $(this).css('background','#ffffff');

        $('#attention_pilotes').hide();
    }
});

}
```

Any clue?

Comment: continue: `return;`  break: `return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "break" an `.each()` loop by returning `false` from the callback function. Returning `true` or just using `return;` is like a "continue".

```
$('.check_dizaine').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
        $('#attention_pilotes').show();
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #daa421');
        $(this).css('background','#f8ecc9');
        return false; // <--- *** Return false here ***
    } else {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #a1a1a1');
        $(this).css('background','#ffffff');
        $('#attention_pilotes').hide();
    }
});
```

But I think it would be better to do something like this:

```
var showWarning = false;
$('.check_dizaine').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
        showWarning = true;
        return false;
    }
});
if (showWarning) {
    $('#attention_pilotes').show();
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #daa421');
    $(this).css('background','#f8ecc9');
} else {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #a1a1a1');
    $(this).css('background','#ffffff');
    $('#attention_pilotes').hide();
}
```

That way, you execute the code in the else-block at most once. Not once for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thx, your solution was good and it does help me to solve my problem! Thx.